What does 也 mean here?
What does 也 mean in this sentence?
秦以恒应该是不想穿别人穿过的拖鞋。
家里临时找不到新拖鞋，楚义也不强求，……。
Context: Chu Yi asked Qin Yi Heng to put on house slippers and come into the house, but he declined. The sentences came after he declined.
Thanks in advance.

也: classical final particle of strong affirmation or identity， i.e. yeah
yes: Old English gise, gese "so be it!," = that
Old English Nominative Case Masculine that: se (the daddy of the)
Old English Nominative Case Neuter: that: þæt
Þ, þ: was replaced by th because Þ, looked a lot like y, as in Ye Olde Tea Shoppe (Y should be Þ, giving: the)
秦以恒应该是不想穿别人穿过的拖鞋。
秦以恒 probably doesn't want to wear slippers which others have worn.
家里临时找不到新拖鞋，楚义也不强求，
Unable to find new slippers, 楚义 did not insist,
Eek, other people's foot fungus!

For this case, 也 acts as a model particle, emphasizing/stressing the tone of the negative expression after it.

一点儿也不错。(emphasis "不错")

一点儿也不馬虎。(emphasis "不馬虎")

楚义也不强求, (emphasis "不强求" - "not insisting", which indirectly demonstrates his mild/easygoing manner, and willingness to compromise)


https://zh.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B9%9F

Could you please elaborate more about what would be different if 也 wasn't used?

It (without 也) will make the sentence less emphatical -  一点儿不错。一点儿不馬虎。楚义沒/未强求.

When is this type of 也 used?

This is a huge task. This article may help to some extent. https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22not_at_all%22_with_%22yidianr_ye_bu%22  Also this, https://context.reverso.net/%E7%BF%BB%E8%AF%91/%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87-%E8%8B%B1%E8%AF%AD/%E4%B9%9F%E4%B8%8D
